# how to sort array in forward and reverse manner Javascript

Tags: javascript

I  am trying to play with an array. I created two buttons `PushUP` and `PushDown`. `PushUp` button will sort the array in forward manner and `PushDown` in reverse manner.  I am trying so hard but failed to figure out but failed to do so. What should I write in order to get the following output. Also, how would I show this data before clicking any `Push` button and then change the order by button accordingly. For example, initially I want to show 2 buttons with the data.

For example, output should be something like that on clicking the following buttons.

```
Original array:

1 xyz
2 abc, 123
3 asd

On clicking PushUp:

3 asd
1 xyz
2 abc, 123

On clicking PushDown:

1 xyz
2 abc, 123
3 asd
```

My code:

```js
var details = [
{intro: "ABC"},
{due: " MON"},
{name: "XYZ", sn: "SN xxxxx"},
{lab: "Tuesday 4:30-6:30"}
];
function Push_Up(){
   details.sort();
   displayPUSH();
}
function displayPUSH() {
    document.getElementById("up").innerHTML =
    "<br>" +
    "CSIT128" + " :" + details[0].intro + "<br><br>"      + 
    "Assignment 5"+ ", " + details[1].due   + "<br><br>"    +
     details[2].name + ", " + details[2].sn + "<br><br>" +
    "Computer LAB" + " :" + details[3].lab + "<br><br>";
 }
 function Push_Down(){
    var details_after ="";
    for ( var i=0; i<details.length; i++ )
    {
        displayPUSH(); 
    } 
    document.getElementById("down").innerHTML = details_after;
 }
```

```html
<button onClick="Push_Up()"> Push Up </button>
<br>
<div id="up">
</div>

<button onClick="Push_Down()"> Push Down </button>
<br>
<div id="down">
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Is your data static?

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: So basically your data will be always same as 1 xyz
2 abc
3 asd

On clicking PushUp:

3 asd
1 xyz
2 abc

Comment: So basically, your data will always be like this :

1 xyz
2 abc
3 asd

when pressed up and 
3 asd
2 xyz
1 abc

on press down?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to [circular shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift) the items, not sort them. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is something like rotation or circular shift but not exactly sorting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do [circular shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift), here's one possible approach:

```js
let data = [
  'foo',
  'bar',
  'baz'
];

function output() {
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = data.map(item => `<li>${item}</li>`).join('');
}

document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const first = data.shift();
  data.push(first);
  output();
});

document.getElementById('down').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const last = data.pop();
  data.unshift(last);
  output();
});

output();
```

```html
<button id="up">Push Up</button>
<button id="down">Push Down</button>
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

Comment: Yes this exactly what I need. But, Is it in JQuery ?? I didnt learn that so far. I need it to be done with javascript only. i pasted your code to .html and tried to run via Chrome and its not working.

Comment: It's not using any library, but it does use some modern JavaScript features like "fat arrows" or string interpolation. Have you tried running the code using the "Run code snippet" button?

Comment: Yes, "Run code snippet" runs perfectly fine. I need this code on .html file to run on chrome.

Comment: Try this gist: https://gist.github.com/petrbroz/411854de5a404385fc70686c36d2457c.